# Self Driving Car Android "opencv.dir" not setup in local properties - Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, opencv, gradle, android-ndk

I've imported a project to Android Studio downloaded from here: https://github.com/Petroula/Android-Car-duino , and I would like to know how can I add opencv.dir to the path. I'm using Android Studio 2.3, please if someone knows how to fix it.

In github readme says:

> 4. Set paths in the local.properties file
>
> If you are using gradle from command line or terminal, you have to
>   create the file manually.
>
> If you are using android studio, first import the project, then add
>   the ndk dir to the created file.
>
> The local.properties file should contain the following lines, and must
>   NOT be added to git:
>
> sdk.dir= **ANDROID SDK DIR** ndk.dir= **ANDROID NDK DIR** opencv.dir=
>   **OPENCV ANDROID SDK DIR** Windows file separators ('\') and drive letter separators (':') must be escaped ('\') .The following is an
>   example:
>
> sdk.dir=F:\Java\Android\android-sdk
>
> ndk.dir=F:\Java\Android\android-ndk-r10d
>
> opencv.dir=F:\OpenCV\OpenCV-android-sdk

[opencv.dir unused property Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okmMm.png)

I have already added the dependency for the library.

Help please... I'm new in Android

Comment: Nice to put a bounty on it, but this seems to be way outdated, esp. as it's referring to Android Studio 2.3.

Comment: @FlorianEchtler I was wondering if someone can post a solution w.r.t newer versions.

Comment: For that specific "Car-duino" project, or for OpenCV with Android Studio in general?

Comment: General opencv with Android ofcourse. @Florian and you could consider Linux also in the answer, it would excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Get the OpenCV SDK from Source Forge:

```
wget https://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/3.4.10/opencv-3.4.10-android-sdk.zip
unzip opencv-3.4.10-android-sdk.zip
```

Clone this fork ([updated and fixed](https://github.com/Petroula/Android-Car-duino/compare/master...syslogic:master)):

```
git clone https://github.com/syslogic/Android-Car-duino
cd ./Android-Car-duino
```

Create a `local.properties` file:

```
cat > local.properties <<EOF
sdk.dir=/path/to/android-sdk
ndk.dir=/path/to/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669
opencv.dir=/path/to/OpenCV-android-sdk
EOF
```

Then build:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention and effort.